# Update listview after asynctask completion

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

How do i update listivew when async task is done. Below is the sample code but the listview isn't updated.

```
    class CallXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    int gcid;
    int scid;

    public CallXML(int gid, int sid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        gcid = gid;
        scid = sid;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // here goes the xml parsing....
        }   

        return null;            
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
       Log.e("TAG", "In postExecute");


       Cursor cur3 = database2.query("Quote", qfield,  null, null, null, null, null);
       cur3.moveToFirst();

       do {
        quotesarray.add(cur3.getString(2));

       }  while (cur3.moveToNext());

        if(cur3 != null){
            cur3.close();
        }

        QList.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                mAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                QList.setAdapter(mAdapter);    
             }
         });


        if (helper2 != null) {
            helper2.close();
        }

        if (database2 != null) {
            database2.close();
        } 

    }
}
```

EDIT:

Acutally `onPostExecute` is not executed why..This is the way I call `asynctask new CallXML(gcid, scid).execute();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, `onPostExecute` is on the main thread so should not be doing database queries there. Instead, get data in `doInBackground` and return the final collection from there.

`onPostExecute` can be used for UI updates and updating your adapter with result collection.

Edit: posting a runnable

```
 QList.post(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                    //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    QList.setAdapter(mAdapter);    
                 }
             });
```

is not required since you are in the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing string items to the adapter in your code. And you don't need to call notifyDataSetChanged when you are setting adapter to a list, because when you set an adapter, it automatically loads the data into list. Perhaps you me try doing it in this way:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
       Log.e("TAG", "In postExecute");

       Cursor cur3 = database2.query("Quote", qfield,  null, null, null, null, null);
       cur3.moveToFirst();

       mAdapter = new CustomAdapter();

       do {
        mAdapter.add(cur3.getString(2));

       }  while (cur3.moveToNext());

        if(cur3 != null){
            cur3.close();
        }

        QList.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                QList.setAdapter(mAdapter);    
             }
         });


        if (helper2 != null) {
            helper2.close();
        }

        if (database2 != null) {
            database2.close();
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u got any error? if so please post it. If not Check the size of data you got from database and if you want to refresh listview just call    listview.invalidateViews() it will refresh the list view and set the new data in the listview.